# How to create jquery tabs using php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I used jquery-ui tabs using php but it's not working, I am unable to identify the problem, please help me.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

        <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "123456", "gazette");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM gazette_details");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "<ul>";
            $id = '#tabs-' . $row['id'];
            echo "<li>" . "<a href='$id'>" . $row['gazette_id'] . "</a>" . "</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="tabs-12">1</div>
            <div id="tabs-13">2</div>
            <div id="tabs-14">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

I used this website example:  http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: have you include jquery library file in your page

Comment: Mind copying the code to JSFiddle?

Comment: yaa i include the library, without php its work, when i use php its not working

Comment: @James Hunt this code copying from http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: you should not mix `html` and `php` in this way. actually thats not oop like. you may have a lookt at [SMARTY Template System](http://www.smarty.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try

```
<?php   
    $ARR_RESULT = array();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "123456", "gazette");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM gazette_details");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ARR_RESULT[] = $row;

    }
    mysqli_close($con);

?>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach($ARR_RESULT as $arr)
            {
                echo '<li><a href="#tabs-'.$arr['id'].'">'.$arr['gazette_id'].'</a></li>';
            }
        ?>
    </ul>

        <?php
            foreach($ARR_RESULT as $arr)
            {
                echo '<div id="tabs-'.$arr['id'].'">';
                echo '<p>Tab-'$arr['id'].'</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>


</div>
```

Comment: you should remove the echo lines from the part where you fill the array. otherwise you will have a wired output :) and this still is a way i would not programm like. mixing php with html is not very oop like.